# Fast search for the coordinates of the maximum value in a gaussian kernel

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, max

I have a simple code that generates a 2D gaussian kernel using [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) function.

Here's the `MWE`:

```
def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(0., 10., N)

# Data lists.
x_data = random_data(10000)
y_data = random_data(10000)

# Obtain the KDE for this region.
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x_data, y_data]), bw_method=0.05)
```

and here's the result:

[image]

What I need is a way to obtain the `x,y` coordinates of the *maximum value* in this KDE.

For what I could gather from various sources the direct way to locate the maximum value seem to be evaluating the `kernel` on a fine grid and then just use `np.argmax` to find it, see below:

```
# define grid.
xmin, xmax = min(x_data), max(x_data)
ymin, ymax = min(y_data), max(y_data)
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])

# THIS IS TOO SLOW.
k_pos = kernel(positions)

# Print max value.
print k_pos[np.argmax(k_pos)]

# Print x,y coordinates of max value.
print positions.T[np.argmax(k_pos)]
```

The issue with this is that evaluating the kernel is **terribly slow**, almost to the point of being unusable for not too large datasets.

Is there a better way to get the coordinates of the max value?

Also accepted (perhaps even better since it would also allow fast plotting): is there a *faster* way to evaluate the kernel in a fine grid?

Comment: If you bin your data first, then you can use convolution and fft. statsmodels fft based KDE only works for 1d, but there are 2d recipes in python available.

Comment: @user333700 Binning the data would result in a loss of precision in the end coordinates.

Comment: use `np.unravel_index(np.argmax(k), k.shape)` to get the coordinates from the argmax

Answer (score -1):

```
np.argmax(kernel)
```

might be what you're looking for...

see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Comment: Nope, already tried that. It returns the value `0`. Thanks anyway!