# Python - Get the coordinates of densest point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kernel-density, argmax

I'm using numpy and scipy to generate a density plot from 3D coordinate information. I can generate a density plot of the data successfully by generating a KDE with the following code

```
xyz = np.vstack([x,y,z])
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(xyz)
density = kde(xyz)
```

But how can I use this information to find the coordinates that associate with the 3D point of greatest density?

I've tried

```
max(density)
```

which returns a value that I can then find the index of with

```
density.argmax(axis=0)
```

but then I hit a blank as I can't seem to use that index to grab the associated coordinates from xyz and I'm unsure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690397/fast-search-for-the-coordinates-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-gaussian-kernel), I can use

```
xyz.T[np.argmax(density)]
```

to return the 3D coordinates of the densest point in my data